# Reattaching a screen in a crontab to wait until the screen closes returns "Must be connected to a terminal."

Tags: bash, cron, gnu-screen

I use a [bash script](https://github.com/JPaalman/Minecraft-Server/blob/master/minecraft.bash) to backup a minecraft world, which is called from a crontab every day. Though the backups are made just fine, I've found an error message in the output:

```
Must be connected to a terminal.
```

I suspect the error is thrown when I try to reattach the screen the Minecraft server is in, after stuffing the stop command. I'm doing this to ensure the `stop` function will wait until the server is actually closed, as I don't want to make a backup while the world is still saving. It works as intended when I manually stop the server using the script.

My question: why is this error being thrown, and is there anything I can or have to do about it?